# reassigning a bool value to NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

i have an NSArray with bool values: 
        NSArray* boolResults = [super foo:values];
how can i change the value in cell 0?

i tried the following:
        boolResults[0] = @NO;
this results in an error: Expected method to write array element not found on object of type 'NSArray *'

and also this:
        BOOL* b = &[[array objectAtIndex:i] boolValue];
got the following error: Address expression must be an lvalue or a function designator

i don't wish to convert this NSArray to NSMutableArray in order to set this value, is there a normal way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `NSArray`s are immutable. You could reassign your pointer to the array with a modified `NSArray`.

```
NSArray *anArray = [super foo:values]
NSMutableArray *mutableCopy = [anArray mutableCopy];
// change your mutable copy and then reassign
anArray = [mutableCopy copy];
```

And just like `NSArray`, `NSNumber`s are also immutable, so something like `[anArray[0] setBoolValue:NO]` does not exist.

Answer (score 4):

If the array isn't mutable, then you can't change that value. The solutions are two:

1. Make the array mutable;
2. Let the array contain mutable objects.

Since you don't want to use a mutable array, I'll make you an example with the second solution. Since there isn't a mutable number in the standard framework, I'll wrap it into NSMutableData. The example supposes that you have an array with a single object, with value @YES, and you want to change it to @NO:

```
NSNumber* number= @YES;
NSMutableData* data=[[NSMutableData alloc]initWithData: [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: number]];
NSArray* array= @[data];   // Now you have an array with a single value
// You want to change the first value to @NO:  
number= @NO;
[array[0] setData: [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: number]];
```

Comment: `boolResults[0] = @NO;` is correct if `boolResult` is an `NSMutableArray`